# Beginner reading fortran code but cant understand this bit

Tags: function, parameters, fortran

I am trying to understand a Fortran code for an internship but I  am a c++ programmer and I am stuck what this code bit does. can some one enlighten me?

```
real(kind=kind_real), pointer :: c(:,:,:)  (I think this created a pointer to a matrix )

self%c => self%gfld3d(:,:,ioff+1:) (this is in the constructor of the class)

flds%c(ibx,iby,2:flds%nc*flds%nl:2) (this is a function that calls the c variable of the class but I don't understand how the parameters work and what does the colon operator do as a a parameter)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `real(kind=kind_real), pointer :: c(:,:,:)`

As you already wrote, this line declares a pointer variable `c` that points to a 3-dimensional array of `real` numbers of the kind `kind_real`. The colon here means that the sizes for each dimension are yet unknown. Assuming this is inside a `type` block, `c` is a member of the type. Notice that in Fortran, `()` is used both for array subscripts and for function calls.

- `self%c => self%gfld3d(:,:,ioff+1:)`

In the constructor, the pointer is assigned a target, which is a portion of the 3-dimensional array `self%gfld3d`, which is also a member of the same type. Pointers in Fortran contain information about the dimensions of the array slice they point to. In this case, the first two colons mean that the array slice spans the whole two first dimensions of the target array. `ioff+1:` means that in the third dimension, the pointer target includes all values in the `self%gfld3d` starting from the given value `ioff+1`. This is a simplified case of the general slice notation, where `a(start:end:step)` represents a slice of the array `a`, starting from index `start`, ending at `end`, in steps of `step`.

- `flds%c(ibx,iby,2:flds%nc*flds%nl:2)`

Based on the above, this is not a function call. It is an expression that evaluates to a 1-dimensional, non-contiguous array slice. From the target of `flds%c`, at indexes `ibx` and `iby` in the first two dimensions, it contains every second value in the third dimension, starting at the index 2 and stopping at `flds%nc * flds%nl`. The first two dimensions in the output array are left out, since the indices in those dimensions are simple scalars. This expression cannot be on its own in a statement, so I assume you left some part of the line out in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I left a little bit out thinking it wasn't necessary. 
About the last paragrapf of your answer; shouldn't flds%c then point to the submatrix of gfld3d  with x size starting from 0 to ibx, y starting from 0 to iby, and then z starting from 2 until flds%nc* flds%nl, stepping by 2 at each time? 
I couldn't understand why you mean a 1 dimensional slice since it seems  3 d to me.

Comment: I am assuming that `ibx` and `iby` are integers. Since no colon is present in those dimensions, those indexes are simply scalars, and that dimension is not included in the output array slice.

Comment: be very careful with non-scalar indices. Fortran's array computing is very powerful. 
A single variable with no colon does not necessarily mean scalar variable. Here is an example: `integer :: ibx(5) = [2,3,1,1,5]; real :: RealArray(6) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; write(*,*) RealArray(ibx); end`. This would print `2.00000000       3.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       5.00000000` if you compile and run it

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the comments:
Unless specifically defined otherwise, fortran arrays always start with element number 1 and then have elements numbers 1 up to the dimension.

```
real(kind=kind_real), dimension(3) :: a
real(kind=kind_real), dimension(0:2) :: b
real(kind=kind_real), dimension(5:7) :: c
```

These three static, real valued arrays all have three elements each. Array 'a' starts at element a(1), array b at element b(0) and c at element c(5)

Comment: adding the note that the keyword `dimension` is not necessary, so this would also work: `real(kind=kind_real) :: b(0:2)`